Keycloak token exchange - automatically link identity providers
I've set up two IDPs (Google and Facebook, for now) on Keycloak and I'm using them for exchanging their access tokens for internal ones provided by Keycloak running on my machine.
Both integrations behave as expected but the problem that I currently have is that Keycloak refuses to automatically link another identity provider if the user was already created (in Keycloak's database) previously, through another identity provider.
What I mean is that if I log in using Google's IDP, a new user is created (as expected), then log out and then try logging in with Facebook's IDP (same e-mail address, also treated as a username) Keycloak complains that the user already exists (or vice versa, first Facebook then Google).
I can manually link another IDP to an existing user using the Admin UI but I'd like this process to be automated.
I'm obtaining the internal tokens (access and refresh) via a HTTP call from my backend to the openid-connect/token Keycloak's endpoint where the grant_type parameter is defined as urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange. I'm also defining the subject_issuer, subject_token and subject_token_type parameters, of course.
Manual linking, after which Keycloak stops complaining that a user already exists:

I've tried adding a custom authentication flow for the two configured IDPs but to no avail:

Is it even possible to automate this linking process? Thank you in advance.
EDIT: I'm running Keycloak (version 24.0.4) in a container and Postgres (version 16.3) as its database.

For a reason: Keycloak has no means to verify the actual identity of said user. It cannot be sure that the remote IDP verified the identity via email. I would consider it to be a major security risk for account Hijacking if that was possible.

You should link using the external-IDP provided "unique identifier". This might not be the email, but maybe some kind of "sub" (OIDC specific). And because the two external-IDP will most likely return two different unique identifier, KC interprets them as "different" users. Don't trust the external-IDP's email address, unless the external-IDP is able to provide some kind of "verified" flag for the email address.
You should plan your merging strategy based on those identifiers.
